# jsctags : tags not sorted

Tags: javascript, vim, exuberant-ctags, jsctags

I am new to using jsctags. I need tags to browse javascript code. I am populating tags through following command:

```
//filtering few files which may not be important for tagging<br>
find . -name "*js" -type f | grep -v '.*node_modules.*node_modules' | xargs -IFILE jsctags FILE -f > .tags
```

The generated tags is unsorted. How do I sort it ?

Besides, any other way to browse javascript code ?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: btw, I am getting strange issue. sort <tag-file> shows good output on console. however, sort <tag-file> -o <sorted-tag-file> generates empty sorted-tag-file. Have never seen such an issue with 'sort' cmd on linux.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the generated file has empty lines, and they appear at the beginning after sorting - remove them using sed:

```
find . -name "*js" -type f | grep -v '.*node_modules.*node_modules' | xargs -IFILE jsctags FILE -f | sort | sed '/^$/d' > .tags
```